# Am I add the item in front of linked-list correctly

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

In this case, I need to implement `addFront()` method which is to keep adding a integer in front of a linked-list.

```
    class Node{
    public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    }
    class List {

    void addFront(int item);

    protected: 
    Node* dummyNode;
    int numItems; //number of item is the linkedlist
};
```

Below is what I tend to implement `addFront()`:

```
  void addFront(int data){
    Node* head = new Node();


    if(numItems == 0) //if no item in the list.
    {
      //Set the head node to be dummyNode
      head = dummyNode;

      //Because the next node the head is pointing to is NULL.
      head -> next = NULL;
    }

    //Create a new node.
    Node* newNode = new Node();

    //Set value
    newNode->data = data;

    //Let the previous pointer of dummyNode points to newNode.
    head->prev = newNode;

    //Re-set head to be newNode.
    head = newNode;

    numItems++;
}
```

Am I doing correctly? If not, why? If yes, is there any better way to do this?

Comment: @JohnDibling it's up to you.

Comment: No. For one, you're leaking memory on the initial insertion. You're also not initializing `dummyNode` to nullptr on construction of `List`. You never check `dummyNode` for nullptr prior to dereferencing it. And that's without even trying to *run* this. So in order of what was asked, (a) No, (b) Because you don't know how to write a linked list, and (c) The last question is moot after the first two. And dissing the first guy that asked you anything about the question is *not* the way to start things off.

Comment: @FlowerFire:  If it's up to me than I'm going to assume this is not homework and you are working on production code.  In that case my answer is that you have **failed** from the start by deciding to implement your own linked list.  Now, I'll ask you again -- is this homework?

Comment: Does it work? If it works, then it is "correct" (but perhaps not how others would implement).

Comment: @JohnDibling No. I typed every word for asking this question without copying and pasting.So, do you still consider it to be a homework?

Comment: Why is `dummyNode` actually called dummyNode?  If it was my list I'd call it, ohh, maybe `m_HeadNode`, but that's just me.  And that's a hint.  ;-)

Comment: @FlowerFire:  Have it your way.  I asked if this was homework because it would effect *how* I helped you, not *if* I helped you.  Since you insist on dodging the question and demonstrating a lack of good faith, I see no reason to invest my time and effort in helping you.  I'm also going to vote to close as NARQ since a person asking a real question would be invested in getting the best answers possible.

Answer (score 1):

I won't go into too many details as this appears to be a homework assignment, but the short answer is, no.

```
Node* head = new Node();
if(numItems == 0) //if no item in the list.
{
    //Set the head node to be dummyNode
    head = dummyNode;
    //...
}
```

You have a memory leak in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

First of all name dummyNode which denotes the beginning of the list looks strange. It would be much better to substitute it for head. Also you need a variable that will point to the tail of the list.

As for your function then it is simple

```
void addFront( int data )
{
    Node *head = new Node();
    head->data = data;
    head->next = dummyNode;
    dummyNode->prev = head;
    dummyNode = head;
    numItems++;
}
```

Also it would be not bad if class Node had a constructor with parameters that to accept data and pointers. Class list also has to have an explicitly defined default constructor or its data members have to be initialized when they are defined.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So what you are saying seemed like I missed a variable to point to the tail of the list right?

Comment: Yes you are  right. Otherwise it will be difficult to add an element to the tail of the list. So I would define in class List Node *head, *tail;

Comment: Yes, that's what I tend to do. I just want to find a tricky way to solve this problem. By the way, could you please edited on my code based on this? Thanks.